# How do I represent the data of combo box as integer

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

In my project, there is a combo box "status" with the three values active, in active and working. As per the requirement the selected value should represent as a integer, so I wrote code so that the index of the selected value will store. Now the problem is, when I tried to select the value from the combo box while updating the status, it should be shown as value in the listview. That if I select 0 it should show active, 1 as in-active and 2 as working.
The code so far I used to get the values is below, please help me getting the values to that integers.

```
private void btnUpdateSupport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Helper.getconnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            string SupportName = txtSupportName.Text;
            string SupportDesignation = txtSupportDesignation.Text;
            //string SupportStatus = txtSupportStatus.Text;
            string SupportStatus = cbSupportStatus.SelectedItem.ToString();
            //string SupportStatus = SqlCommand();
            int i = 0;
            string s = "Active";
            // string result = int.TryParse(s, out i);

            if (cbSupportStatus.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                int x = int.Parse(cbSupportStatus.SelectedItem.ToString());
            }
            else
            { //Value is null }

                cmd.CommandText = "Update Status1 set Designation='" + SupportDesignation + "', Status='" + SupportStatus + "' where Name= '" + SupportName + "' ";
                MessageBox.Show(cmd.CommandText);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

            }
        }
```

Comment: can you not use ComboBox.SelectedIndex? That will give you the 0-based integer of the selected item

Comment: Yes, that is okay, using the selected index I am able to store the index value to database, now the problem is I want to pull the corresponding value of that index in the other form to update.

Comment: So the combo box only has numbers, and you want the list box to show 'what the numbers mean'? In that case, when the item is added to the list box, simply change the number to the text it should be

Comment: Yes, the combo box has only numbers 0, 1 and 2. when I select 0 from the combo box, it should show as active in the list box, I am unable to code that, if possible please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, the combo box only has the numbers 0, 1 and 2

I am assuming that these numbers are stored from 1 form into a database (?) then retrieved in another form, where you want:

- 0 = active
- 1 = inactive
- 2 = working

to be displayed in a listbox

Why not just do:

```
string listVal = "";
if(storedVal == 0)
{
    listVal = "Active";
}
else if(storedVal == 1)
{
    listVal = "Inactive";
}
else if(storedVal == 2)
{
    listVal = "Working";
}

if(listVal != "")
{
    // add to listbox
}
```

EDIT
Or instead of storing the number in a database, store its meaning, then just retrieve that text for the listbox

Comment: Yes, let me see if it helps, Thanks much for helping me, I will be always grateful to you --Karthik